# android GoogleMap is null, displays fine but can't add markers/polylines

Tags: android, dictionary, null, supportmapfragment

I have a GoogleMap which displays fine (within a SupportMapFragment) and uses the GoogleMapOptions for the target camera location. However, I am unable to add markers/polylines to the GoogleMap. Here is the method for creating the map:

```
private void createMap(List<LatLng> latLngs) {

    if(map == null) {
        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
        map = mapFragment.getMap();

        float zoom = 13;
        CameraPosition cameraP = new CameraPosition(latLngs.get(0), zoom, 0, 0);
        options.camera(cameraP);


        //TODO MAP IS NULL - SORT OUT!
        // check it has been instantiated
        if (map != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "map is not null");
            map.clear();
            //Calculate target zoom, based on trip size
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraP));
            // Add LatLngs to polyline

            PolylineOptions poly = new PolylineOptions().color(Color.RED);
            MarkerOptions startMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLngs.get(0)).title("Start");
            MarkerOptions endMarker = null;
            if(latLngs.size() > 1) {
             endMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    latLngs.get(latLngs.size() - 1)).title("End");  
            }

            for (LatLng latLng : latLngs) {
                poly.add(latLng);
            }

            map.addPolyline(poly);
            map.addMarker(startMarker);
            map.addMarker(endMarker);

        }


        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.trip_summary_map_container, mapFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

As you can see from the inline comments, the map is still null (although it is displaying and using the options). Just can't add things to it. I assume I am not instantiating it properly?

The Activity extends FragmentActivity, and I have set up all the necessary stuff for using the Maps API.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I have posted a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032667/1555605) with the solution I prefer to use now.

I had the same problem some days ago and I solved it extending `SupportMapFragment` class so that it executes a callback method once the map is finally ready.

```
public class ExtendedSupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    public static interface MapReadyListener {
        public void mapIsReady(GoogleMap map);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static SupportMapFragment newInstance() {
        return null;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public static SupportMapFragment newInstance(GoogleMapOptions options) {
        return null;
    }

    public static ExtendedSupportMapFragment newInstance(MapReadyListener mapReadyListener) {
        ExtendedSupportMapFragment fragment = new ExtendedSupportMapFragment();
        fragment.mapReadyListener = mapReadyListener;

        return fragment;
    }

    private MapReadyListener mapReadyListener;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (mapReadyListener != null)
            mapReadyListener.mapIsReady(getMap());
    }

}
```

Then you just need to do something like this:

```
public class RutaMapaFragment extends SherlockFragment implements ExtendedSupportMapFragment.MapReadyListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragmentMapa = ExtendedSupportMapFragment.newInstance(RutaMapaFragment.this);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void mapIsReady(GoogleMap map) {
        //Do whatever you want with your map.
    }

}
```

Comment: So simple and actually obvious, but have been loosing hair on a similar issue. Works nicely!

Answer (score 1):

So, time has passed and all. The fact is that I don't use the solution in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15335553/1555605) anymore, but prefer to use a `ViewTreeObserver` instead. The following code shows a rather simple fragment with a `SupportMapFragment` being added to it.

The method `createMap()` adds the `SupportMapFragment` and then executes `setupMap()`, but only via a `OnGlobalLayoutListener` that will basically be executed once the map is actually ready. Of course, this listener is removed immediately—there's no need to keep it there any longer.

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private View mMapContainer;
    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(/* ... */);
        // ...

        mMapContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.map_fragment_container);
        createMap();

        return view;
    }

    private void createMap() {
        mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.map_fragment_container, mMapFragment)
                .commit();

        mMapContainer.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            mMapContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            mMapContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }

                        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
                        setupMap();
                    }

                });
    }

    private void setupMap() {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Marker & PolyLines in the map using below code:

> ```
> GoogleMap mMap;
> static final CameraPosition BONDI =
>         new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(-33.891614, 151.276417))
>                 .zoom(15.5f)
>                 .bearing(300)
>                 .tilt(50)
>                 .build();
> changeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(BONDI));
>     mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.891614, 151.276417)).title("Bondi"));
>  private void changeCamera(CameraUpdate update) {
>     changeCamera(update, null);
>     }
> /**
>  * Change the camera position by moving or animating the camera depending on the state of the
>  * animate toggle button.
>  */
> private void changeCamera(CameraUpdate update, CancelableCallback callback) {
>     boolean animated = ((CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.animate)).isChecked();
>     if (animated) {
>         mMap.animateCamera(update, callback);
>     } else {
>         mMap.moveCamera(update);
>     }
> }
> ```

Add the PolyLines as below:

```
 // A simple polyline with the default options from Melbourne-Adelaide-Perth.
    mMap.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
            .add(BONDI));
```

Comment: all looks good, but before implementing something like that, my map needs to be present - it is still null, and can not be manipulated.

Comment: Please check that you have defined all the needed permissions & map key in your manifest.

Comment: I have, I can add markers/polylines when including the map fragment in the layout xml file for the activity, all works fine. But I want to load the LatLngs from a web service (which works fine) and create a map programatically once the LatLngs are loaded. The map is created after they are loaded, however it doesn't add the markers/polylines because it is null and therefore can not be manipulated.